# How do I publish a .NET Core ASP.NET website that targets framework net461?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I need to publish a .NET Core ASP.NET Website for IIS that targets framework net461.

I've tried:

```
dotnet publish --runtime active --output "C:\stuff\" --configuration Release
```

but this results in the project being output as a **.exe** (along with .dlls of the dotnet core dependencies like Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.dll). I need to publish to IIS on a Windows Server 2008 R2.

```
"buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true,
    "warningsAsErrors": true
},
"dependencies": {
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.Elm": "0.1.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0"
},

"frameworks": {
    "net461": {}
},
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: an .exe will be part of the published content, in addition to a web.config and some other web artifacts that iis can use.  You might need to add some additional steps.  See [this article on publishing to iis](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html) for a complete set of instructions.

Comment: There's an issue with the --output options, remove it, it will publish in bin/release/net461/publish

Comment: @stephen.vakil is there anyway to publish it as a .dll? 
if I use framework: netcoreapp1.0, I'm able to get a .dll, but I need to target net461.

Comment: There may be, but I'm not aware of it.  The recommended deployment is to have IIS act as a reverse proxy to Kestrel, which means an `exe` will be involved.  A little more info [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/servers.html) though it doesn't precisely answer your question.

Comment: @johnluke.laue If you had a pure .Net Core 1.0 application, you could choose to publish it as a `DLL` (Portable application) or `EXE` (Self-contained application). Depending on this, your web.config would have different settings for IIS to run the application.

Comment: @Ignas How do I tell if I have a pure .Net Core 1.0 app? Also, how can I "choose" to publish the app as a .DLL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to get an `exe` output for IIS using .Net Core ([Self-contained application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/dotnet-publish)).

I used following command to publish a test site:

`dotnet publish --configuration Release --output "C:\temp\net461-site"`

Pointed IIS to `C:\temp\net461-site` (must have `web.config` file), changed App Pool CLR version to `No Managed Code` and the site works.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I did what you said, but now I'm getting an IIS HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure. I asked a new question regarding this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39752807/deploy-net-core-asp-net-website-http-error-502-5-process-failure

Comment: @johnluke.laue so do I get my answer accepted or up-voted? :)

Comment: I got it working with the EXE, but is there anyway I can make it a DLL?
@Ignas

Comment: If you were using pure .Net Core 1.0 you would need to specify `platform` type for the `Microsoft.NETCore.App` dependency. However, this doesn't seem to be compatible with `net461` ...

Comment: know if it's compatible with net462?

Comment: Not sure about net462, however it might become possible in .Net Core 2.0 next year - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/07/15/net-core-roadmap/

Comment: The 502.5 error comes because ``dotnet publish-iis`` doesn't work any more so the ``web.config`` file is not modified to point to the correct executable. The Azure launcher apparently can not handle the ``%LAUNCHER_PATH%`` and ``%LAUNCHER_ARGS%`` variables and decides to die instead. Modifying the web.config manually works. I'm trying to get around this myself but visual studio resets my web.config on every build :/