# Deploy .NET Core ASP.NET Website - HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I'm trying to publish the template project "ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework)" from Visual Studio 2015 to IIS.

I use the Visual Studio publish to File System feature.

I'm using Windows 10.

I followed the guide from [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html).

- I set up a website in IIS and changed the Application Pool .NET CLR Version to No Managed Code
- I instaled the .NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle
- I restarted my machine.

I get this error:

[image: HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure]

I added a logs folder, but no logs get created.

Any ideas on how I can solve this?

**EDIT:**

Output of running the .exe from powershell:

PS C:\TestCoreWebsite> .\Web_CoreWebNetFramework.exe
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: C:\TestCoreWebsite
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

Then I navigate to http://localhost:5000 and the sample site works.

Comment: does it work running on IIS Express?

Comment: Try running the `exe` file directly and see if you get any errors. If yes, please post them here, if not then there is an issue with IIS set up - web.config, file/folder permissions.
Common errors are defined here: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html#common-errors

Comment: @Ignas The .exe works when I running it directly from powershell. I'll look into the file/folder permissions issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution:

In the root web.config change:

```
processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%"
```

to:

```
processPath=".\Web_CoreWebNetFramework.exe"
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran the following command in cmd

```
C:\fullpath\dotnet C:\fullpath\PROJECT.dll
```

on the command prompt, which gave me a much more meaningful error:

> "The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '1.0.1' was
>   not found. - Check application dependencies and target a framework
>   version installed at: C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App - The following versions are
>   installed: 1.0.0 - Alternatively, install the framework version
>   '1.0.1'.

I Installed the correct net core and the project worked correctly

Answer (score 0):

With VisualStudio 2017, open up the .csproj file and add to the first   block:

```
<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>1.0.4</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
```

Usually the result will be:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>1.0.4</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

For whoever faces the same issue as mine(running well in VS but got above issue when deploying into Local IIS), I missed Setting Environment Variable and It works after I added the Setting Environment Variable
[image]

Ref: [How to add Setting Environment Variable in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31049152/publish-to-iis-setting-environment-variable)